# Перемоножить каждое число в массиве

Tags: python

Есть два массива

```
c = np.array([4,4,4])
cc = np.array([[2,2]])
```

Пытаюсь перемножить их следующим образом

```
correct_predictions=np.dot(c[0],cc)
```

На выходе получаю `[[8 8]]`

Вопрос, как перемножить каждое число второго массива на каждое число первого массива, что бы на выходе получить примерно сл. `[[8,8],[8,8],[8,8]]`
На ум приходит только цикл, может есть другое решение?

Comment: вопрос не совсем корректный. Какой результат вы ожидаете получить для `cc = np.array([[2,3]])` ? А еще лучше приведите ожидаемый результат для `c = np.array([1,2,3]); cc = np.array([[4,5]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([4,4,4])
cc = np.array([[2,2]])

cc * c[:, np.newaxis]
array([[8, 8],
       [8, 8],
       [8, 8]])

cc = np.array([[2,3]])
cc * c[:, np.newaxis]
array([[ 8, 12],
       [ 8, 12],
       [ 8, 12]])
```